# Count values until the first empty cell

Tags: google-sheets

What I looking for is how to count as many values in column, but I want it to stop counting as soon as it hits the first empty cell. I am trying to do it without using app script.

Example:

```
1
2
312
EMPTY
3123
```

Should return 3, if I simply use COUNTA(), it will return 4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your "empty" cells are indeed BLANK then you can use the following:
`=ArrayFormula(match(TRUE,ISBLANK(A1:A13),0)-1)`
(as long as there is always an empty row between the sets of "Years"

- the `ISBLANK(A1:A13)` returns an array result {FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,...}
- the `match()` returns the POSITION or ROW of the first `TRUE` in that list : 4
- we then take away 1, for the empty row
- we have to run the whole thing as an array formula because we need ISBLANK() to work on each cell in turn.

if they contain text "EMPTY" then use:
`=ArrayFormula(match(TRUE,if(A1:A13="EMPTY",TRUE,FALSE),0)-1)`

Comment: Just an FYI to those not familiar with Array formulas: remove ArrayFormula() and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. So the final formula will be: =match(TRUE,if(A1:A13="EMPTY",TRUE,FALSE),0)-1

Comment: This is true for both google sheets and excell, but the question specifically referred to google sheets, which will accept a typed array formula (exactly as in my answer) confirmed with just an enter.

Comment: Presuming the arbitrary choice of 13 rows to actually mean all rows, use A:A to get the whole column.
Also, additional to Excel functionality, Google sheets supports entire columns (or rows) to be referenced **starting at an offset**. For example, A6:A (or B5:5). To me, this is *the* killer feature that puts it apart from Excel.

Comment: Could the same be done for the whole column? It seems to apply only if you have a rough idea of the number of rows.

Comment: @EricBurel yes, no reason why not: you can just use `=ArrayFormula(match(TRUE,ISBLANK(A:A),0)-1)` for a whole column

or to only start from a specific cell, but go to the end of the column: `=ArrayFormula(match(TRUE,ISBLANK(A5:A),0)-1)`